# Borders of Eretz Yisrael: Ibn Ezra

Tags: eretz-yisrael, tehilim-psalms, avraham-ibn-ezra

In his commentary on [תהלים פרק צח פסוק ג - Psalm 98:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.98.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [Ibn Ezra](https://www.sefaria.org/Ibn_Ezra_on_Psalms.98.3.1?lang=bi) writes as follows:

> זכר, כל אפסי ארץ - כנגד מקומות הישוב שהם שבעה גבולות בצפון ואחד בדרום

I have been unable to determine which גבולות, borders, 7 to the north and 1 to south, Ibn Ezra is referring to.

Any explanations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ibn Ezra is not referring here to the borders of Israel at all. He is translating the phrase אפסי ארץ - the ends of the earth - and is describing the entirety of human habitation, as known to him.

He uses the phrase שבעה גבולות בצפון to refer to the [seven climes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clime) (or climata) of the northern hemisphere, originally proposed by Claudius Ptolemy and later adopted in Arabo-Persian astronomy.

Ptolemy's seven climes are horizontal divisions of the earth into bands, reaching from the equator until a latitude of 48°32' N. Each clime was supposed to have a different level of suitability for habitation.

The phrase אחד בדרום, as far as I can tell, is a reference to Ptolemy's belief that the earth was actually inhabited south of the equator as well, down to a latitude of 16°25' S (see his [Geography, 1.10](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=_9Ri1Lx21bIC&pg=PA25#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

For more on Ibn Ezra's use of the term גבולות for the climes, see S. Sela, [Abraham Ibn Ezra and the Rise of Medieval Hebrew Science, pp. 107-112](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=HvCns2cU6f0C&lpg=PA107&ots=je95AIuevA&dq=ibn%20ezra%20seven%20climes&pg=PA107#v=onepage&q&f=false).

For more on medieval Jewish conceptions of the earth's habitability, see Resianne Fontaine, [Between scorching heat and freezing cold: Medieval Jewish authors on the inhabited and uninhabited parts of the earth](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/15460419.pdf).

Comment: +1 fascinating!

Comment: @Harel13 Thank you! I had a good time researching this one...

Comment: Thank you Joel.  great answer. I would never have gotten this myself.  Now let me see if I can take it further